# JQuery-Mobile scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

I use this css codes to make scroll bar visible in jquery-mobile:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:vertical {
    width: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar:horizontal {
    height: 12px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color:#CE0003;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: grey;
}
```

When I open the page with mobile the scroll bar is visible but swiping on it, isn't working (It wont scroll the page). How can I fix this issue?
You can see it in this [**fiddle 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/eylay/bzwrxdgg/6/)

**UPDATE:**
If you think its impossible to do it this way ,there's another way using *jquery*.
In this [**ffidle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/eylay/nxvcpt4w/3/) you can see that a function has been written which detects ***swipe down*** and ***swipe up*** on a div. Now it just needs a function that scrolls the page.

Comment: Why are you bothered about scroll bars on mobile devices? The whole point is that it's natural to simply swipe - scroll bars are way too small for us to use anyway with average size hands/fingers

Comment: @DarrenSweeney I'm using an application which gives me an html file and i have to include it by <iframe>. swiping on the iframe not working and has no solution, So I have to make a scrollbar.
http://qeshmbook.com/mobile.html Its my website you can check (With Mobile) to understand me better.

Comment: I have tried iscroll (http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5) or other written scroll bars but I cant use them WITH iframe

Comment: What are you attaching the scroller to? body?

Comment: If you mean in my website, I havent attached it to anything, I've just written those css codes to make scroll bar visible.

Comment: The bigger issue here is that you're using an iframe on mobile. You should instead use ajax to put the content directly on the page and get rid of the iframe. Then you don't need to worry about scrollbars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can and want use jquery, this is a good plugin for scroll bar replacement. Is simple and work great and it is very configurable. But you must override some CSS for your style and needs.

```
$(".container").mCustomScrollbar({ scrollbarPosition: 'outside' });
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/nxvcpt4w/9/) the example (tested on mobile too).

And [this](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) is the plugin site and doc.

Comment: Tnx. Its a really good plugin. Im trying to fix a problem. the scroll bar is not visible, check my website http://qeshmbook.com/nnn.html its an hour im trying the figure out where the problem is! I try more, Hope It be solved...

Comment: I first thought the problem is using jquery-mobile but this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eylay/bzwrxdgg/10/ showed the problem is something else.
I am exactly doing the same thing in the fiddle for my website but Im trying to figure out the problem...

Comment: In your page there are more than one error. Use the chrome debug console (or your browser debug console). First you must call jquery JS and then the plugin. The first error you must resolve is : "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mCustomScrollbar is not a function", change the order of js file init... and then wrap the init into the document ready, this: "$(document).ready(function(){ $(".container").mCustomScrollbar({ scrollbarPosition: 'outside' }); });". So try and see.

Comment: I see your edited html. The command is "$(document).ready" and not "document.ready" :) F12 on chrome, and you can see all the error of your js.

Comment: Oh!!! The mistake is why I havent slept for a long time!!!!
Tnx Its still not visible and im still seeking for the errors! Hope I find it...

Answer (score 2):

Using the example from your second fiddle as a beginning, you could do this:

```
//From the fiddle
var supportTouch = $.support.touch,
            scrollEvent = "touchmove scroll",
            touchStartEvent = supportTouch ? "touchstart" : "mousedown",
            touchStopEvent = supportTouch ? "touchend" : "mouseup",
            touchMoveEvent = supportTouch ? "touchmove" : "mousemove";
    $.event.special.swipeupdown = {
        setup: function() {
            var thisObject = this;
            var $this = $(thisObject);
            $this.bind(touchStartEvent, function(event) {
                var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                        event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                        event,
                        start = {
                            time: (new Date).getTime(),
                            coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ],
                            origin: $(event.target)
                        },
                        stop;

                function moveHandler(event) {
                    if (!start) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var data = event.originalEvent.touches ?
                            event.originalEvent.touches[ 0 ] :
                            event;
                    stop = {
                        time: (new Date).getTime(),
                        coords: [ data.pageX, data.pageY ]
                    };

                    // prevent scrolling
                    if (Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 10) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                }
                $this
                        .bind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler)
                        .one(touchStopEvent, function(event) {
                    $this.unbind(touchMoveEvent, moveHandler);
                    if (start && stop) {
                        if (stop.time - start.time < 1000 &&
                                Math.abs(start.coords[1] - stop.coords[1]) > 30 &&
                                Math.abs(start.coords[0] - stop.coords[0]) < 75) {
                            start.origin
                                    .trigger("swipeupdown")
                                    .trigger(start.coords[1] > stop.coords[1] ? "swipeup" : "swipedown");
                        }
                    }
                    start = stop = undefined;
                });
            });
        }
    };
    $.each({
        swipedown: "swipeupdown",
        swipeup: "swipeupdown"
    }, function(event, sourceEvent){
        $.event.special[event] = {
            setup: function(){
                $(this).bind(sourceEvent, $.noop);
            }
        };
    });
```

And then add

```
$('.scrollbar').on('swipedown', function(){
    var SCROLL_FRACTION = 3;
    var height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var width = document.body.scrollWidth;
    scrollTo(width, height - height / SCROLL_FRACTION);
});
$('.scrollbar').on('swipeup', function(){
    var SCROLL_FRACTION = 3;
    var height = document.body.scrollHeight;
    var width = document.body.scrollWidth;
    scrollTo(width, height + height / SCROLL_FRACTION);
});
```

And then you can just change `SCROLL_FRACTION` to whatever fraction of the page you want to scroll when you swipe.